# How to avoid addition element to list when use else during while loop in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I have a problem, when I use my code and write down 'no' my program adds it to the list instead to move to >else< block without addition 'no'.

```
listagosci = []
print("Party list: ")
for i in range(3):
    n5 = input("enter name of guest: ").title()
    listagosci.append(n5)
n5 = input("Would You like to add another guest? (yes/no): ").title()
while n5 != "No":
    n5 = input("enter name of guest, if no, eneter \"no\": ").title()
    listagosci.append(n5)       
else:
    print(listagosci, len(listagosci))
```

I create the solution can add after else listagosci.remove(-1) - but in my opinion program shouldn't add this 'no'.

As well I know there is no if statment when someone just write something different in n5 input than yes/no but I don't need it at the moment.

I tried everything what I know (I'm beginner).

Comment: Think about how your program executes: first, `n5 = input(...)`, then, immediately, `listagosci.append(n5)`. There must be something in between that checks if `n5` is "No".

Comment: Why do you have a `for i in range(3):` loop to get the first guest??

Comment: @JohnnyMopp in workbook there is info that we need to add 3 guests and after use while loop with condition.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if n5 != "No":` after `"enter name of guest, inf no, eneter \"no\": "` would do the trick.

Full code:

```
listagosci = []
print("Party list: ")
for i in range(3):
    n5 = input("enter name of guest: ").title()
    listagosci.append(n5)
n5 = input("Would You like to add another guest? (yes/no): ").title()
while n5 != "No":
    n5 = input("enter name of guest, if no, eneter \"no\": ").title()
    if n5 != "No":
        listagosci.append(n5)       
else:
    print(listagosci, len(listagosci))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you need to do is add an additional check before appending to the list:

```
listagosci = []
print("Party list: ")
for i in range(3):
    n5 = input("enter name of guest: ").title()
    listagosci.append(n5)
n5 = input("Would You like to add another guest? (yes/no): ").title()
while n5 != "No":
    n5 = input("enter name of guest, if no, eneter \"no\": ").title()
    if n5 != "No":
        listagosci.append(n5)
else:
    print(listagosci, len(listagosci))
```

Comment: Yes I done it without else block cuz if works alone because else duplicates the if statment. But the problem is still alive. 'no' is added to the guest list.

Comment: @Adorovosky, "no" and "No" are two different strings. You must be specific about which one you want to treat as special. Or convert the input to all-caps (for example) and treat "NO" as special.

Comment: @Adorovosky Try to be more specific. You're appending to the list in two places: in the *for* loop, and in the *while* loop. The code I showed prevents the append if the string `n5` is "no" inside the *while* loop. You could also add the same `if n5 != "No":` check inside the *for* loop.

Comment: @Adorovosky Also, if you are just learning Python, I recommend that you use a code visualizer such as [this one](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html), so that you can see step by step what Python is doing.